# Adding Header & Footer for all screens in JSPDF

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm Trying to add a header and footer in all screens while downloading PDF. I have added table with mock data using jspdf-autotable and able to download it. But the header is coming only in last page of the downloaded PDf

I need some help in getting Header and footer with page number in all screens. Kindly help.

Code in sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/upbeat-cannon-cfiry?file=/src/App.js:0-1257

Code here :

```
import jsPDF from "jspdf";
import "jspdf-autotable";
import { datas } from "./data";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import PdfDocument from "./PdfDocument";
export default function App() {
  const columns = [
    { title: "Rank", dataKey: "Rank" },
    { title: "Name", dataKey: "Name" },
    { title: "count", dataKey: "count" }
  ];

  var rows = datas?.map((data) => ({
    Rank: data?.Rank,
    Name: data?.Name,
    count: data?.count
  }));

  const downloadPdf = () => {
    const string = renderToString(<PdfDocument />);

    var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt");
    doc.setFontSize(20);
    doc.setTextColor(40);
    doc.setFontStyle("normal");
    doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
      startY: doc.autoTable() + 70,

      margin: { horizontal: 10 },
      styles: { overflow: "linebreak" },
      bodyStyles: { valign: "top" },
      columnStyles: { email: { columnWidth: "wrap" } },
      theme: "striped",
      showHead: "everyPage"
    });
    doc.fromHTML(string);

    doc.save("random.pdf");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={downloadPdf}> Download PDF </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AutoTable` provides a list of hooks for customizing the content and styling of the table.

You can use `didDrawPage` hook for adding Header and Footer to your pages. You can do something like this:

```
doc.autoTable(columns, rows, {
  startY: doc.autoTable() + 70,

  margin: { horizontal: 10 },
  styles: { overflow: "linebreak" },
  bodyStyles: { valign: "top" },
  columnStyles: { email: { columnWidth: "wrap" } },
  theme: "striped",
  showHead: "everyPage",
  didDrawPage: function (data) {

    // Header
    doc.setFontSize(20);
    doc.setTextColor(40);
    doc.text("Report", data.settings.margin.left, 22);

    // Footer
    var str = "Page " + doc.internal.getNumberOfPages();

    doc.setFontSize(10);

    // jsPDF 1.4+ uses getWidth, <1.4 uses .width
    var pageSize = doc.internal.pageSize;
    var pageHeight = pageSize.height
      ? pageSize.height
      : pageSize.getHeight();
    doc.text(str, data.settings.margin.left, pageHeight - 10);
  }
});
```

Result:

[image]